# JWT throw Error: secretOrPrivateKey must have a value in nest.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, jwt, nestjs

**auth.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { JwtModule, JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { User, UserSchema } from '../user/entities/user.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => {
        return {
          global: true,
          secret: config.get<string>('JWT_SECRET'),
          signOptions: {
            expiresIn: config.get<string | number>('JWT_EXPIRES'),
          },
        };
      },
    }),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }]),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, JwtService],
  exports: [MongooseModule, AuthService, JwtService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { User } from '../user/entities/user.entity';

import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { LoginDto } from './dto/login.dto';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(User.name)
    private userModel: Model<User>,
    private jwtService: JwtService,
  ) {}

  async login(loginDto: LoginDto): Promise<{ token: string }> {
    const { username, password } = loginDto;

    const user = await this.userModel.findOne({ username });

    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid email or password');
    }
    if (user.password !== password) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid email or password');
    }
    const token = await this.jwtService.signAsync({ id: user._id });

    return { token };
  }
}
```

**auth.guard.ts**

```
import {
  CanActivate,
  ExecutionContext,
  Injectable,
  UnauthorizedException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Request } from 'express';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { User } from '../user/entities/user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(User.name)
    private userModel: Model<User>,
    private jwtService: JwtService,
    private readonly configService: ConfigService,
  ) {}

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const token = this.extractTokenFromHeader(request);
    if (!token) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException(
        'You are not authorized to access this resource.',
      );
    }
    try {
      const payload = await this.jwtService.verifyAsync(token, {
        secret: this.configService.get<string>('JWT_SECRET'),
      });
      console.log('payload ->>', payload);
      const user = await this.userModel.findById(payload.id);

      if (!user) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException('User not found.');
      }
      request['user'] = user;
    } catch {
      throw new UnauthorizedException(
        'You are not authorized to access this resource.',
      );
    }
    return true;
  }

  private extractTokenFromHeader(request: Request): string | undefined {
    const [type, token] = request.headers.authorization?.split(' ') ?? [];
    return type === 'Bearer' ? token : undefined;
  }
}
```

When i called login API then i got

> Error: secretOrPrivateKey must have a value

I have go through some answer on stackoverflow. Its says remove the `JwtService` from the provider in `auth.module.ts`.

I have also tried this but its give me another error

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthGuard (UserModel, ?,
> ConfigService). Please make sure that the argument JwtService at index
> [1] is available in the BookModule context.

I don't know what am i missing

Thanks in advance

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you either didn't define your env variables or that the ConfigModule is set up wrongly. According to [the official NestJs documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration) you must include the `ConfigModule.forRoot()` in your AppModule imports. For handling various env files (for example `.development.env`) you must specify the path for them like this:

```
ConfigModule.forRoot({
  envFilePath: '.development.env',
});
```

Also, last but not least, check for typos in your env file. It should include a value for `JWT_SECRET`. And although this is unrelated to the original problem, consider using a library like `zod` for validating your .env files to avoid typos or tedious env debugging.

Comment: I have already setup configuration 
ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: '.env',
      isGlobal: true,
    }),